# Getting Route in Laravel Package's Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

How do I get **Route name** in a `Laravel 5.4` vendor package's `middleware` ?

This is how my package and middleware in question is structured.

```
vendor
-Student
--Pickachoo
--src
---PickachooServiceProvider.php
---Controller
---Middleware
----StudentMiddleware.php
---Routes
---Views
```

This is how I am trying to access the route name in the middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    dd( $request->route()->getName() );
    return $next($request);
}
```

This `$request->route()->getName()` is supposed to return the route name, right ? But it is returning null.

I tried adding middleware in 3 ways, but nothing worked, it returns `null` every time.

I am adding my middleware `StudentMiddleware` in `PickachooServiceProvider` as follows :

```
public function boot(\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router)
{
    /*Register middleware*/
    $router->aliasMiddleware('authenticate', 'Student\Pickachoo\Middleware\StudentMiddleware');
}
```

Instead I tried adding the middleware in `app/http/kernel.php` arrays `$middleware` and `$routeMiddleware` separately without any success.

The route:

```
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function(){

    Route::get('/test', function() {
        echo 'Something';
    })->middleware('authenticate');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {

            dd(\Request::route()->uri);

            return $next($request);
        }
```

Comment: it is showing you the current uri u request  to visit. die dump the route object that contains lot of information

Comment: not working in laravel 8 
 Trying to get property 'uri' of non-object